# Rails page caching appends strange symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

When I enabled page caching in rails, I noticed that the strange character `Â` is appended to symbols like `©`, `«` and `»`.

For example

```
© Company 2013
```

becomes

```
Â© Company 2013
```

and also

```
«  => Â« 
»  => Â»
```

I have no idea why is this happening. Any suggestions how this can be solved?

- Rails 3.2.11
- ruby 1.9.3p194
- web-server: WEBrick 1.3.1
- OS Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be confuse with encodings.

Try to add meta header with UTF-8 charset to your application right after opening head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```